# Overwrite a function depending on given parameters, during initializing Child class #Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

It's a minimum example of python inheritance:

```py
class Parent(object):
     def __init__(self, time):
         self.time=time
     def forward(self):
         return 0
 
class Child(Parent):
     def forward(self):
         return 1
```

I want to overwrite the `forward` function based on `self.time` when initializing `Child` class.

I.e. if `self.time==2`, use Parent's forward function instead of Child's.

```py
class Child(Parent):
     def __init__(self, time):
         super(Child, self).__init__(time)
         if self.time==2:
             pass
             #todo: use super().forward instead
     def forward(self):
         return 1
```

Can I achieve it in python (3.8+)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods can be assigned dynamically in Python:

```py
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, time):
        super(Child, self).__init__(time)
        if self.time == 2:
            self.forward = super(Child, self).forward

    def forward(self):
        return 1
```

Or you can call `Parent.forward` in `Child.forward`:

```py
class Child(Parent):
    def forward(self):
        return super(Child, self).forward() if self.time == 2 else 1
```